# How to Remove specific columns from a file using more than one delimiter

Tags: linux, unix

I have a file in the below format.

```
Input File
-----------
01$@!AA$@!Team1$@!01-JUN-2018$@!City2
01$@!AA$@!Team1$@!01-JUL-2018$@!City2
02$@!BB$@!Team2$@!10-JUN-2018$@!City1
02$@!BB$@!Team2$@!10-JUL-2018$@!City1
```

I would like to Remove 3rd and 5th Column in the file based on delimiter($@!).

```
Output File
-----------
01$@!AA$@!01-JUN-2018
01$@!AA$@!01-JUL-2018
02$@!BB$@!10-JUN-2018
02$@!BB$@!10-JUL-2018
```

I have tried with cut command. It is working fine with one delimiter($) here i am using delimiter($@!).

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example. You can set your field separator to be $@! then print the field numbers you want (with FS as the separator). This will print fields 1, 2, and 4, excluding 3 and 5:

```
awk -F'\\$@!' '{print $1 "$@!" $2 "$@!" $4}'
```

So using your input file, the output would be:

```
01$@!AA$@!01-JUN-2018
01$@!AA$@!01-JUL-2018
02$@!BB$@!10-JUN-2018
02$@!BB$@!10-JUL-2018
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working. is there any specific method to remove the columns instead of printing the selected columns.

Comment: You could use an awk for loop and add a conditional to skip the unwanted columns: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html